Installed Raylib but it's not showing up in c drive
enter image description here
Using "C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe" instead so I am unable to use Raylib header file. Installer said it was being installed in C:\raylib folder but after installation is completed I can't see any such folder in c drive.
I am not sure if the problem has anything to do with visual studio code, as I had trouble setting it up. I should mention I am a beginner.
I reinstalled it multiple times and did the regular restart windows but it seems to stay the same, if the Raylib file showed up in c drive then maybe I would have needed to add it to system environment variables path.


Make sure you installed gcc correctly by running gcc --version in the terminal
if it doesn't show the version add the gcc.exe folder path to your system environment
variables How to add a path to the PATH environment variable
Download Raylib and extract it
And then run g++ [Your Main File] -o [Your exe name] -L"[Your Raylib Library Path]" -lraylib -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -lwinmm. Change what is in []. For example, my command setup is
g++ main.cpp -o main -L"D:\Files\Raylib\lib" -lraylib -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -lwinmm
Run the exe

I hope that helps.
